# Execute JS function from HTM

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a little function I wrote to display current day of the week on the page

```
   function displayDay(){
      var d = new Date();
      var dy = d.getDay();
      var day = "Day";
      switch(dy){
        case 0:
          day = "Sunday";
          break;
        case 1:
          day = "Monday";
          break;
        case 2:
          day = "Tuesday";
          break;
        case 3:
          day = "Wednesday";
          break;
        case 4:
          day = "Thursday";
          break;
        case 5:
          day = "Friday";
          break;
        case 6:
          day = "Saturday";
          break;
      }
        document.getElementById("display-day").innerHTML = day;  
    }
    displayDay();
```

Html:
`Enjoy the rest of your <span id="display-day"></span>`

It works but on other pages, that do not have the `span#display-day`, `innerHTML` throws an error and prevents execution of the further functions in the js file.

I'm trying to execute the function from the HTML so only one page executes this function, but it's not working. Here's the code added to html

```
<script>
   displayDay();
</script>
```

and `displayDay();` is removed from the JS file of course. But it isn't working, I can't find any resource to explain how to execute functions this way so I would appreciate if someone could guide me.

Comment: just put condition `if(document.getElementById("display-day")) {document.getElementById("display-day").innerHTML = day;  } `

Comment: the last line in your function sets the inner html of element with id=display-day to calculated day. so you can replace it with code that will put it to right place or return it from function and reuse in more generic way

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev Hey your method works, I tried `if($('#display-day').length == 0) { document.getElementById("display-day").innerHTML = day; }`

It didn't work because even if the span existed, it was still empty. Thanks for your take

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition statement like the following:

```
var element = document.getElementById("display-day");
if (element) {
  element.innerHTML = day; 
}
```

`document.getElementById` returns null if it finds nothing.

Answer (score 0):

just modify your script tag like that :

```
<script>
   if( document.getElementById("display-day") ) displayDay();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be three reasons for this not working properly:

1. The script inside you html is executed *before* your js file so that `displayDay` is not defined yet. Make sure your function is declared before your script is executed.
2. `displayDay` is not defined in the global scope (i.e. window) so it cannot be accessed outside its container. `var` being function scoped in javascript, it would mean that `displayDay` is created inside another function (which is very typical justly to avoid polluting the global scope with your script's variable). To ensure displayDay is accessible anywhere, make it is defined outside any englobing function or attach it to the `window` object: `window.displayDay = displayDay;`.
3. You are trying to update the content of the span before this span has actually been created by the browser. To avoid that put your script at the end of your page or wait for the `onload` event.

Here is a working jsfiddle.

```html
Enjoy the rest of your <span id="display-day"></span>


<script>
// Replace this script by your js file inclusion.
// It would also work if you put it in the header though it is usually better
// to append all your scripts at the end of the body to avoid delaying the
// page rendering.
(function(){
  function displayDay(){
    var d = new Date();
    var dy = d.getDay();
    var day = "Day";
    switch(dy){
      case 0:
        day = "Sunday";
        break;
      case 1:
        day = "Monday";
        break;
      case 2:
        day = "Tuesday";
        break;
      case 3:
        day = "Wednesday";
        break;
      case 4:
        day = "Thursday";
        break;
      case 5:
        day = "Friday";
        break;
      case 6:
        day = "Saturday";
        break;
    }
    document.getElementById("display-day").innerHTML = day;  
  }
  // displayDay is still only accessible on the parent anonymous function here.
  window.displayDay = displayDay;
  // now we attached it to window so it is accessible everywhere.
}());
</script>

<script>
// This is after the span declaration so I could just execute displayDay. 
// However it is good practice to avoid DOM manipulation while
// the onload event hasn't been received yet. 
window.addEventListener("load", displayDay);
</script>
```

Comment: All scripts are before the body closing tag, jquery is the first, then the file that includes the function, and then the script tag that calls the function. Your jsFiddle works but I sstill couldn'd get it to work on my page. It says displayDay is not defined

Comment: OK then it is probably because your function is not declared in the global scope (i.e. window). As a result you cannot access it outside its container. I'll edit my answer to reflect this other possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Just put condition

```
if(document.getElementById("display-day")){
    document.getElementById("display-day").innerHTML = day; 
}
```